# Access a database from Broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, broadcastreceiver

I cant access my `SQlite` database from my `broadcast receiver`. Is it even possible? I keep getting a `NullPointerException`.  In the `onReceive of the BroadcastReceiver` I call

```
mDbHelper = new ResponderDbAdapter(context);

mDbHelper.open();
```

Is it something to do with the context?  I want to pull database info that gets set in my `MainActivity` into the `BroadCast Receiver`.

Ideas?

EDIT :

```
ERROR:
07-29 16:43:46.491: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6772): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-29 16:43:46.491: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6772): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.test.example.feed.receiver.RecieveSMS: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-29 16:43:46.491: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6772):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1805)
07-29 16:43:46.491: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6772):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-29 16:43:46.491: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6772):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:981)
07-29 16:43:46.491: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6772):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-29 16:43:46.491: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6772):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-29 16:43:46.491: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6772):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3684)
07-29 16:43:46.491: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6772):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 16:43:46.491: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6772):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-29 16:43:46.491: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6772):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:845)
07-29 16:43:46.491: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6772):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:603)
07-29 16:43:46.491: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6772):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-29 16:43:46.491: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6772): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-29 16:43:46.491: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6772):     at com.test.example.feed.receiver.RecieveSMS.onReceive(RecieveSMS.java:67)
07-29 16:43:46.491: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6772):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1794)
07-29 16:43:46.491: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6772):     ... 10 more
```

EDIT: A Better Explanation

I have a separate activity that allows the user to add items to the database.  I want to share this with the receiver so that the broadcast receiver knows what items are in the database. ResponderDbAdapter is a class that accesses the Db and performs fetches and inserts to the DB.  What would the context be...if I have the broadcast receiver running even if the application is closed how can it access a database?

Comment: Yes, it's possible (I do it in my app), but you're going to need to post some more of your code or at least the stack trace.

Comment: Can you explain how you do it? I've added the stack trace

Comment: You need to make sure you are using the correct context.  It's also possible the broadcast receiver is terminating before you get a chance to access your database.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that `ResponderDbAdapter` extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`? If not, then you might want to tell us what it is, since it's not in the Android documentation (and thus likely not part of the standard library).

Comment: The context you receive should be for your application.  And the database operations in the construction of the database helper are blocking calls, so the broadcast receiver shouldn't be terminating.  What line of code is at this point in the NPE stack trace: com.test.example.feed.receiver.RecieveSMS.onReceive(RecieveSMS.java:67)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Broadcast Receivers version of the context is probably not working for the DBHelper. Have the Receiver fire up a service and have the service access the DB