# How to access database from Broadcast Receivers in its onReceive method?

Tags: android

I am unable to access DBHelper Class from OnRecieve method.
How to access Database Handler class from Broadcast Receiver so that CRUD operations can be done easily

Comment: post your Broadcast Receiver

Comment: At least show some of your code.

Comment: possible duplicate of
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877555/access-a-database-from-broadcast-receiver

Answer (score 0):

Do **NOT** do database I/O in a `BroadcastReceiver`. `onReceive()` is called on the main application thread. If your UI happens to be in the foreground when `onReceive()` is called, that UI will be frozen while your I/O is going on. If you take substantial time (several seconds), Android will terminate your code in the middle of what you are doing, as the background equivalent of an "Application not responding" (ANR) dialog.

If you have disk I/O, database I/O, network I/O, etc. that needs to be triggered by a broadcast, do that I/O in an `IntentService`, and have `onReceive()` call `startService()` to trigger the `IntentService`. If this work may take substantial time, consider using a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`.